# Unwanted multiple instances of the same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my controller:

```
var page = 2;

$($window).scroll(function () {
    if($($window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $($window).height()) {
        myService.addMore(page);
        page++;
        console.log("page: " + page);
    }
});
```

This function runs when you scroll to the bottom of the page. The function then calls myService with the page value as a parameter.
The service function is just a http request like this:

```
factory.addMore = function (page) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "url..." + page,
    }).success....
}
```

Every time you scroll down, the service makes a http request with the page value and some data gets printed to the view. While the page variable adds 1 every time, which it should.

However, there is a problem if you trigger the function by scrolling down, and then navigate to another page on the site, and then back again to the page with the scroll function.

The console.log outputs this:

- You scroll down, output: page: 3
- Scroll down more, output: page 4
- Change page, then back to scroll page and scroll down again, output: page 5
  and page: 3

So now suddenly it seems like i have two of these functions running, which is a problem. How can i fix this? The page value should reset to 2 every time you go back.

I'm using ui router to change between states.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You might want to use $window from angular instead of jQuery. Also bare in mind that everytime your code is execute "$($window).scroll(function () {", a function is binded to the event. So you might end up binding the function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the listener to the window object. Which persists through states in a single page application. Either unbind the listener at state redirect or bind it to an element that gets deconstucted at state redirect (i.e. something in the template of the state).

Comment: Yeha, you're right. It's the window object that's causing the problem. Tried this instead, and then it works. 

$($window).off().on('scroll', function () { }

Altough that disables another scroll function i have, which is also bound to $window. I tried to bind it to other elements, even body. But by some reason window is the only one that works.

Comment: You can bind a single scroll listener att page instantiation that excecutes all functions in an array/object stored in a factory/service. Then populate the array/object at controller instantiation (if that particular listener does not already exist). This is ofc easier if you use an object with named properties rather than an array.